# What is the best indexes.auto config for a production environment

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

The question is based on configurations explained in http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:indexing

Though `config.setAutoIndex("validate");` seem a good option. An accidental miss in applying config on prod could bring the system down.

So, is there a way to apply index if they are missing with less programmatic effort?

Comment: there's no other way

Comment: This is an upcoming feature for neo4j-ogm. (`update` mode)

Comment: grate, looking forward to it. Where can I follow it?

Answer (score 0):

As [that doc](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:indexing) states, you can just configure `ogm.properties` with `indexes.auto=validate` to avoid having to do anything programmatically.

Comment: Yes, but if the index is missing it just throws exception. Wish, there is a way to apply them if missing.

Answer (score 0):

For simple systems where the schema in the Neo4j database is equal to what is declared in the domain model you could use `assert`.

However this is rarely the case. New `update` option coming in OGM 3.1 will be more usable (it won't drop existing indexes/constraints), but is still not enough for more complicated deployments (e.g . indexes not defined in the domain, multiple applications accessing the db, ...).

Is such cases you should manage the indexes either manually or using some tool, such as http://www.liquigraph.org/, and use `validate` option in your OGM application to verify all expected indexes are present.

When doing so you should check that

- the schema update is not going to affect the existing load (e.g. plan for time with low load)
- existing data match the new schema (e.g. properties for new constraints exist on all nodes)
- indexes/constraints no longer needed are dropped